# Get admin grid's row count Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, grid

If I am creating a block which is type 'Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid'  in my controller like so...

```
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('mymod/adminhtml_mymod_my_grid');
```

I can get the html like so...

```
$block->getHtml();
```

Is there any way I can get the number of rows the grid returns? Something like...

```
$block->getRowTotal();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$block->getCollection()->getSize();` retrieves the count of all items.